# Is machine learning synonymous with neural networking?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What I mean is, when referring to machine learning, does this necessarily mean the use of a neural network? Or are there other ways to implement machine learning that do not use a neural networks?

These terms seem largely superficially synonymous.

Comment: Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Neural nets are one class of machine learning models/algorithms but not the only ones by any measure. ML is a couple decades older than the concept of neural nets, which were first invented in the 60s but not actually viable for use on non-trivial tasks until ~15 years ago when people figured out you can use a GPU to make training viable.

Even today there are ML algorithms/models being worked on/used that are not neural nets. Graph learning, clustering, pattern extraction... You could in theory find a NN to perform all of these tasks, but generally if you have the option to use an algorithm that isn't based on the NN architectures and get the same results, you're going to want to use the non-NN approach since they're resource-intensive and not easy to get right.